# access folder outside CodeIgniter

Tags: image, codeigniter

I've been to trying to upload images using code igniter and it works perfectly when the upload folder is just outside of application folder. But my problem is when I try to access folder which is outside whole code igniter folder it is throwing me a error. How to access the folder outside the code igniter folder? I tried $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. But it dint help.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        if (isset($_FILES['upload']['name'])) {
            // total files //
            $count = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
            // all uploads //
            $uploads = $_FILES['upload'];

            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                if ($uploads['error'][$i] == 0) {
                    $firstimage = $uploads['name'][$i];
                    $secondimage = $uploads['name'][$i];

                    move_uploaded_file($uploads['tmp_name'][$i], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'tuition/tuitionimage/'.$id.'/'.$uploads['name'][$i]);
                    $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                    $config2['source_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'tuition/tuitionimage/'.$id.'/'.$uploads['name'][$i];
                    $config2['new_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'tuition/tuitionimage/'.$id.'/thumbnail/'.$uploads['name'][$i];
                    $config2['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                    $config2['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                    $config2['thumb_marker'] = '_thumb';
                    $config2['width'] = 75;
                    $config2['height'] = 50;
                    $config2['overwrite'] = TRUE;

                    $this->image_lib->initialize($config2);
                    $this->load->library('image_lib',$config2);
                    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
                    {
                        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                    }

                    $config3['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                    $config3['source_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'tuition/tuitionimage/'.$id.'/'.$uploads['name'][$i];
                    $config3['new_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'tuition/tuitionimage/'.$id.'/resize/'.$uploads['name'][$i];
                    $config3['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                    $config3['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                    $config3['thumb_marker'] = '_thumb';
                    $config3['width'] = 470;
                    $config3['height'] = 470;
                    $config3['overwrite'] = TRUE;

                    $this->image_lib->initialize($config3);
                    $this->load->library('image_lib',$config3);
                    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
                    {
                        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                    }

                    }


            }
            $this->load->view('head');
            $data = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'id' => $id
            );
```

Comment: This is very vague. We need a sample of the code you're using to try to access the outside folder and a sample of the directory structure that makes it an outside folder.

Comment: Thank you for updating the post. Is the tuition folder actually in the document_root folder or outside of it?

Comment: Document root. Path is like this. www/tuition/tuitionimage/idvalue/

Comment: If document_root is returning the www/ folder, I don't see why this wouldn't work. Are you getting a specific error from PHP or your webserver?

Comment: move_uploaded_file(C:/wamp/www/tuition/tuitionimage/132/bannerBackground2.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Does the 132/ folder exist? I'm not sure if move_uploaded_file() will succeed if the id folder isn't created yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing in comments, the problem is likely the move_uploaded_file() function is trying to move the file to a directory that doesn't exist yet.

```
move_uploaded_file($uploads['tmp_name'][$i], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'tuition/tuitionimage/'.$id.'/'.$uploads['name'][$i]);
```

Before the file can be moved the folder needs to be created. If $id is new, it has probably not been created yet. So...

```
if (!is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'tuition/tuitionimage/'.$id)) {
    mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'tuition/tuitionimage/'.$id);
}
move_uploaded_file($uploads['tmp_name'][$i], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'tuition/tuitionimage/'.$id.'/'.$uploads['name'][$i]);
```

Comment: Actually there already exists a folder with tat name. Its not that problem

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. The error says the folder doesn't exist. I tried the same code on one of my CI apps and it worked fine.