# Cannot upload images to a folder outside application Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function which  does the upload of an image to a folder in my codeigniter project.

```
 $config =  array(
                     'allowed_types'   => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
                     'upload_path'     => APPPATH."images",      //Uploading to internal folder
                    // 'upload_path'     => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."images/" //Uploading to folder outside application (not working)
                     'file_name'      => $data['user_id'].".png"
                  );
```

I can upload the files in a folder inside application folder,but if I change the path outside application folder it wont get uploaded. No files are found. I have set the permission of the outside folder `777`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302043/access-folder-outside-code-igniter

Answer (score 1):

Try with changing the path to

```
'upload_path'     => "./images/",
```

Answer (score 0):

To save files outside application directory you can provide an absolute URL like:

```
'upload_path'     => "D:/app_images/images/",
```

Else you can go back one level by dot (.) operator like:

```
'upload_path'     => "./images/",
```